# Mitosheet Not able to edit cell values

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, edit, jupyter-lab

I am trying to use `Mitosheet` to edit a `dataframe` in Jupyter Notebook (I've tried using Jupyter Lab - same result), but every time I try to edit a cell, I get an error:

Sorry, there was an error during executing this code.

I double click a cell, turn off the Edit entire column, introduce a new value and click Enter.
And I get this:

[image]

I've reinstalled the mitosheet package, but this did not fix it.

Or here I've tried to edit a text column of a simple dataframe:

[image]

I can edit the numeric column though:

[image]

I've tried reinstalling the package, run it via Jupyter notebook and Jupyter lab, test with different dataframes.
I expect to be able to edit the cell values of all columns in a dataframe.